# Rev slider loading issue in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, video, plugins, slideshow

I have a revolution slider on my WordPress site with a video in my banner. It was working just fine and suddenly I got a black box for about 15-20 seconds before it loaded. In the meantime I've added a banner image as the background for this div so it doesn't just show an empty black container.

I have the same parameters set on my dev site and the video seems to start just fine and right away.

Is it just that it's taking too long to load...? If so, is there a way to make it so that the video loads first?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Contact form 7" plugin is causing this error with "W3 Total Cache plugin" on your Production site. Try disabling Contact form 7 and you will see the results.

Contact Form 7 reloads the page in the background by Ajax when you use it with any caching plugin.